# How to use references in a function for C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I have an assignment, where I have to get grades from a student. Use a function to get the average, and then another function to get a count of how many fall into a certain range. I have no problem getting the function for averaging to work. But the function for counting I’m not sure how to pass the value... The instructor said to use references...I read and researched it...but I just don’t get it... How can I do it?

Here is my code...

```
// Program written by Darius Dempsey

// 2014-03-11
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline double stuAverage(double totalr) // Get average of grades
{
    return (totalr/3);
}

void countAvg(double avgG, int &a1, int &a2, int &a3, int &a4, int &a5) // Get average of grades
{
    int avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5;
    avg1 = 0;
    avg2 = 0;
    avg3 = 0;
    avg4 = 0;
    avg5 = 0;

    a1;
    a2 = 0;
    a3;
    a4 = 0;
    a5 = 0;

    if(avgG>90)
    {
        avg1 = avg1 + 1;
        a1 = avg1;
    }
    else if(avgG>80.00 && avgG<89.99)
    {
        avg2++;
    }
    else if(avgG>70.00 && avgG<79.99)
    {
        avg3 = avg3 + 1;
        a3 = avg3;
    }
    else if(avgG>65.00 && avgG<69.99)
    {
        avg4++;
    }
    else
    {
        avg5++;
    }

    return;
}

void countAvg(double avgG, int &a1, int &a2, int &a3, int &a4, int &a5);

int main()
{
    // Define 2-D array and store values
    int students = 0;
    float grade[students];
    int count = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int totalr = 0;
    float g = 0;
    float avgG;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;

    //double a=a1, b=a2, c=a3, d=a4, e=a5;

    // Get input of grades and imput them into array
    cout << "How many students are there? ";
    cin >> students;

    for(int c = 0; c < students; c++)
    {
        grade[c];
        int stuG = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            stuG = i + 1;
            s = c + 1;
            cout << " please enter grade  " << stuG << " for student " << s;
            cout << " Grades must be between 0 and 100" << endl;
            cin >> g;

            // Verify grade is correct input
            if(g > 0 && g <=100)
            {
                totalr = totalr + g;
            }
            else if(g<0 || g>100)
            {
                c = c - 1;
            }
        }

        grade[c] = stuAverage(totalr);
        avgG = stuAverage(totalr);
        totalr = 0;
        //countAvg(avgG, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<students; i++)
    {
        s = i + 1;
        cout << "average for student " << s << " is " << grade[i] << "\n";
    }

    countAvg(avgG, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);

    cout << "Average grades over 90 =\t\t" << a1 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades between 80.00 - 89.99 =\t" << a2 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades betweem 70.00 - 79.99 =\t" << a3 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades between 65.00 - 69.99 =\t" << a4 << "\n"
    cout << "Average grades less than 65 =\t\t" << a5 << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return(avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5);
```

is problematic. You are returning [just avg5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Examples) here and the rest are all dropped.

Perhaps your instructor asked you to pass parameters by reference. You can read [this swap example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm) to get an idea.

Comment: Ok Thanks everyone for your responses...@mohit  I love the way you guys quickly respond, the only problem i have withthis side is the way comments are set up if your the one who originally asked the question. makes it hard to follow up

Comment: Try to read and understand the example. If you still have any problem, do post it.

Comment: comment field too small

Comment: the comment field to small to show you my rewritten code..i dont get how i'm suppose to show you my code in this little space..This is so frustrating...

Comment: How am I suppose to post it..I can't answer my own question, which is the only area large enough to put code, and format correctly..comment field doesnt format it correctly...

Comment: here is first part of fuction code                                  ;;void countAvg(double avgG, double &a1, double &a2, double &a3,double &a4,double &a5 )//Get average of grades
{double avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5;

Comment: more of function code                                                ...avg1 =a1;
avg2 =a2;
avg3 =a3;
avg4 =a4;
avg5 =a5;

Comment: rest of function code                                              .... if(avgG>90)
   {avg1++;
   }
   else if(avgG>80.00 && avgG<89.99)
   {avg2++;
   }
   
   
   else if(avgG>70.00 && avgG<79.99)
   {avg3++;
   }
   
   else if(avgG>65.00 && avgG<69.99)
   {avg4++;
   }
    else
   {avg5++;
   }
   
   return;
  

}

Comment: call to function using reference                                    ... cout<<"Average grades over 90 =\t\t"<<a1<<"\n";
   cout<<"Average grades between 80.00 - 89.99 =\t"<<a2<<"\n";
    cout<<"Average grades betweem 70.00 - 79.99 =\t"<<a3<<"\n";
     cout<<"Average grades between 65.00 - 69.99 =\t"<<a4<<"\n";
      cout<<"Average grades less than 65 =\t\t"<<a5<<"\n";

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but its the only choice I have to show you my code.. It isn't working..it compiles but the output for the call to reference section is garbage...maybe cell address..or junk..but not the correct output..

Comment: ok what I did was edit the original post to show the new code..that I currently have..@mohit

Comment: This answer is overloaded with comments, so I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to pass all arguments by using (arg1, arg2...) will not work as expected in C++.
You can either do it in two ways:

1) Pass arguments by **reference** (using the `&` in the end of each argument in function definition) or by using **pointers**, so that when you modify a value of a reference/pointer, the modification will apply and to the values of the variables outside the function. You then need to return nothing from the function.

2) Pack all the data you need to return in a **structure** and then "return" that structure.
You can create a structure (I suggest `std::vector`, if you are familiar with STL containers but you can even use an `array`) , put the data in that structure and then return a pointer or reference of it.

What you did seemed to be like a structure return in a dynamic language, like `Python` ((arg1,arg2...) in python will return a structure (`tuple`) of objects).

NOTICE: in the second case, you will have to have the structure dynamically allocated implicitly or explicitly, in order not to have the structure deleted when function call is complete and your pointer/structure pointing to garbage.

Comment: Don't return a pointer or reference to a local variable. It would be out of scope and accessing it may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Nick L... I posted my new code adjustments...It isn't working..it compiles but the output for the call to reference section is garbage...maybe cell address..or junk..but not the correct output..

Comment: Why did you pass the first argument by value?

Answer (score 0):

He wants you to go:

```
void countAvg(double avgG, double &avg1, double &avg2, double &avg3, double &avg4, double &avg5)
```

Then the label `avg1` within `countAvg` denotes the same variable as `avg1` in `main`.  So your changes in `countAvg` persist, and you don't have to return anything.

As someone else said, it'd be tidier to have `avg1` through `avg5` in a container of some sort, instead of this long parameter list.

Comment: Thanks @mattMcNabb... I reposted my new code..It isn't working..it compiles but the output for the call to reference section is garbage...maybe cell address..or junk..but not the correct output..

Comment: Argh. Write what I wrote, and delete `double avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5;avg1 =a1;avg2 =a2;avg3 =a3;avg4 =a4;avg5 =a5;`.  The idea is to actually use the referenced variables,  not to copy them and put your results nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code... It now works...

#### Code

```
// Program written by Darius Dempsey

// 2014-03-11
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

inline double stuAverage(double totalr) // Get average of grades
{
    return (totalr/3);
}

void countAvg(double avgG, int &avg1, int &avg2, int &avg3, int &avg4, int &avg5) // Get average of grades
{
    //int avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5;

    if(avgG >= 90)
    {
        avg1 = avg1 + 1;
        avg1;
    }
    else if(avgG>79.99 && avgG <= 89.99)
    {
     avg2 = avg2 + 1;
    }

    else if(avgG > 69.99 && avgG <= 79.99)
    {
        avg3 = avg3 + 1;
        avg3;
    }

    else if(avgG >= 65.00 && avgG <= 69.99)
    {
        avg4 = avg4 + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        avg5 = avg5 + 1;
    }
    return;
}

void countAvg(double avgG, int &avg1, int &avg2, int &avg3, int &avg4, int &avg5);

int main()
{
    // Define 2-D array and store values
    int students = 0;
    float grade[students];
    int count = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int totalr = 0;
    float g = 0;
    float avgG;
    int avg1 = 0, avg2 = 0, avg3 = 0, avg4 = 0, avg5 = 0;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
    //double a = a1, b = a2, c = a3, d = a4, e = a5;

    // GET INPUT OF GRADES AND IMPUT THEM INTO ARRAY
    cout << "How many students are there? ";
    cin >> students;

    for(int c = 0; c < students; c++)
    {
        grade[c];
        int stuG = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            stuG = i + 1;
            s = c + 1;
            cout <<" please enter grade  " << stuG << " for student " << s;
            cout << " Grades must be between 0 and 100" << endl;
            cin >> g;

            // Verify grade is correct input
            if(g > 0 && g <= 100)
            {
                totalr = totalr + g;
            }
            else if(g<0 || g>100)
            {
                c = c - 1;
            }
        } // Pass average for each student into array
        grade[c] = stuAverage(totalr);

        totalr = 0;
    } // Pass average grade into countAvg function

    for(int i=0; i<students; i++)
    {
       avgG = grade[i];
       countAvg(avgG, avg1, avg2, avg3, avg4, avg5);
    }

    // Out average for each student
    for(int i=0; i<students; i++)
    {
       s = i + 1;
       cout<<"average for student "<<s<<" is "<<grade[i]<<"\n";
    }

    // Output count of each category for average
    cout << "Average grades over 90 =\t\t" << avg1 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades between 80.00 - 89.99 =\t" << avg2 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades betweem 70.00 - 79.99 =\t" << avg3 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades between 65.00 - 69.99 =\t" << avg4 << "\n";
    cout << "Average grades less than 65 =\t\t" << avg5 << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void getRateAndHrs(double &, double &);
double calcPay(double, double);

int main() // Function should display the gross pay on screen
{
    double payRate, hours;
    double WeekPay;
    getRateAndHrs(payRate, hours);
    WeekPay = calcPay(payRate, hours);
    cout << "Weekly pay: " << WeekPay;
    system ("pause")
    return 0;
}

void getRateAndHrs(double & rate, double & Hrs) //
    cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
    cin >> Hrs;
    cout << "Enter hourly rate: ";
    cin >> rate;
    return;
}

double calcPay(double hrsWorked, double hrlyRate)
{
    return hrsWorked * hrlyRate;
}
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting is off because it will not compile (missing "{" near "getRateAndHrs").